# Colorscheme not display correctly for vim on mac terminal

Tags: colorscheme, color

I start up vim from mac terminal like so:

```
vim filename
```

But my colorschemes do not load properly (I tried loading `desert.vim`, `desert256.vim` and `solarized.vim`).

`desert256.vim` has a black background and white text.

`desert.vim` doesn't make a difference.

`solarized.vim` has blue font and grey background.

I tried a lot of solutions online, but cannot get it to work. (like adding lines to `.vimrc`). My current `.vimrc` is:

```
syntax enable
set background=dark
colorscheme desert256
set t_Co=256
let colors_name = "desert"
```

Comment: You shouldnt need to let colors_name or set t_Co (it should be automatically detected). Can you explain what you mean by “do not load properly”? Add your vim version as well. Is this a coloring issue, or is the colorscheme command failing (check runtimepath)?

Comment: if you run `colorscheme darkblue` does it change your background to dark blue?

Comment: Add associated pictures, it would help us understand.

Answer (score 1):

It is very common for a fancy colorscheme (such as solarized, base16-*, you name it) to require palette changes in a terminal. Without it you will face ugly colors.

I generally avoid such colorschemes in terminals and use them only in GUI vim.

To solve it -- goto the place you have obtained colorscheme, find description on how to properly use it. Usually it is smth about changing first 16 terminal colors. Solarized example: https://github.com/altercation/solarized . There you can find how to redefine your colors for different stuff including osx terminal.

PS

There are also colorshemes that are not made with terminals in mind -- they define only gui colors.

Answer (score 0):

Look for colorschemes that are compatible with the terminal and the mac OS terminal colors. Here is a list of them (search for the word "solarized"): https://github.com/rafi/awesome-vim-colorschemes